# Linux device route without broadcast

Tags: linux, routing, network-namespace

I have the following setup:

- A network namespace, `ns1`
- A pair of virtual interfaces, `ns_ext1` and `ns_int1`. `ns_ext` exists in the global namespace, and `ns_int1` exists in `ns1`.
- A GRE device, `gre1`, which exists in `ns1`.
- None of these devices are assigned IP addresses.
- The routing table in `ns1` is as follows

  - `10.0.2.0/24 -> gre1`
  - `0.0.0.0/0 -> ns_int1`
- The routing table in the global namespace includes:

  - `10.0.2.0/24 -> ns_ext1`

When I try to ping `10.0.2.1` from the global namespace, which is an IP address that exists on the other end of the GRE tunnel, I get odd behavior. The traffic is forwarded to `ns_ext1`. However, in `ns1`, `ns_int1` isn't forwarding this traffic to `gre1`, as the routing table says it should. Instead, it's ARP'ing for `10.0.2.1`. My suspicion is that, by specifying the device `ns_ext` as the next hop for the `10.0.2.0/24` subnet in the global routing table, I've made the kernel think that the subnet is directly connected to `ns_ext1`. Is there any way I can get it to just forward through that interface instead of ARP'ing?

Comment: Are you using `iproute2`, right? Can you provide the result of the commands `ip route show table all` and `ip tunnel show`?

Comment: What happens when you try to ping `10.0.2.1` from inside `ns1`? Which device are you seeing ARP packets on? How did you configure the GRE tunnel?